# Full Data Binding to a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to do data binding to a stored procedure, similar  to a table or view ? 
(i.e. including select, update, delete, insert)

for selecting, I'm currently executing the procedure with ExecuteReader(), read it into a DataTable and then bind the table to a grid. But now, how to write back changes from the datatable into the database? Is there a "simple", built-in method in the .NET framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. A stored procedure could produce the returned results in any way possible with T-SQL code and it is not possible to create an update by calling the same procedure as was used to read the data.

A more modern way to work with data access is to use an OR-Mapper such as entity framework. Depending on your type of application (web applications where the data is sent to the client and then posted back and interpreted as new objects are typically a bit harder) it might be possible to do a simple data binding and save the changes back to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with Stored procedure, but something similar can be achieved with `SqlCommandBuilder`

Here is a full sample which describes how to do that http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307587

Comment: Sorry, this  sample is not working with procedures at all. They are using a select statement as basis: `SqlDataAdapter daAuthors = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Authors", objConn); ` This is just standard data binding, and I know all about that. However, I want  to access my  database ONLY through stored procedures. No direct access to tables or views should be given.

Comment: Pls check my answer I clearly stated **It is not possible with Stored procedure**

Comment: Well, OK, but I want a solution which is entirely done via procedures.